# Pandas df.resample(): Specify NaN threshold for calculation of mean

Tags: python, pandas, nan, resampling

I want to resample a pandas dataframe from hourly to annual/daily frequency with the `how=mean` method. However, of course some hourly data are missing during the year.

How can I set a threshold for the ratio of allowed NaNs before the mean is set to NaN, too? I couldn't find anything considering that in the docs...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's not clear what you want to get , post a sample from your data and expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `groupby`.

```
# Test data
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=365*24, freq='H')
number = 365*24
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, number),index=pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=number, freq='H'), columns=['values'])
# Generating some NaN to simulate less values on the first day
na_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=start_date +  3 * Hour(), freq='H')
df.loc[na_range,'values'] = np.NaN

# grouping by day, computing the mean and the count
df = df.groupby(df.index.date).agg(['mean', 'count'])
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

# Populating the mean only if the number of values (count) is > to the threshold
df['values'] = np.NaN
df.loc[df['count']>=20, 'values'] = df['mean']
print(df.head)

# Result
                mean  count  values
2015-01-01  4.947368     20     NaN
2015-01-02  5.125000     24   5.125
2015-01-03  4.875000     24   4.875
2015-01-04  5.750000     24   5.750
2015-01-05  4.875000     24   4.875
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!
Would be nice if this was integrated in the resample function itself....

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative solution, based on resampling.

```
    # Test data (taken from Romain) 
    start_date = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
    pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=365*24, freq='H')
    number = 365*24
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,    number),index=pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=number, freq='H'), columns=['values'])
    # Generating some NaN to simulate less values on the first day
    na_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end='2015-01-01 12:00', freq='H')
    df.loc[na_range,'values'] = np.NaN


    # Add a column with 1 if data is not NaN, 0 if data is NaN
    df['data coverage'] = (~np.isnan(df['values'])).astype(int)
    df = df.resample('D').mean()
    # Specify a threshold on data coverage of 80% 
    threshold = 0.8
    df.loc[df['data coverage'] < threshold, 'values'] = np.NaN
    print(df.head)

    # Result
          values  data coverage
    2015-01-01       NaN       0.458333
    2015-01-02  5.708333       1.000000
    2015-01-03  5.083333       1.000000
    2015-01-04  4.958333       1.000000
    2015-01-05  5.125000       1.000000
    2015-01-06  4.791667       1.000000
    2015-01-07  5.625000       1.000000
```